# get_posts() returns all posts rather than the ones specified with 'post_author' =>

Tags: get-posts

I want to retrieve an array with the posts of a certain user for a custom post type category.

However, get_posts($arg) returns ALL posts of this custom post type, although I specified the post_author

```
<?php $pages = get_posts(array('post_type'  => 'profile','post_author' => $post->post_author)); ?>

<?php var_dump ($pages); ?>
```

In this example $post->post_author is 11. However, the result of the code above is:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(WP_Post)#343 (24) { 
["ID"]=> int(2326)
["post_author"]=> string(2) "11" 
..etc.} 
[1]=> object(WP_Post)#352 (24) { 
["ID"]=> int(2324) 
["post_author"]=> string(1) "0" 
 ...etc.}
[2]=> object(WP_Post)#395 (24) { 
["ID"]=> int(2322)
["post_author"]=> string(1) "0" 
...etc.}
```

Why does get_posts() returns posts of authors whose ID is **not** 11?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`post_author`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters) is not a valid parameter for `get_posts`. You really need to look at `WP_Query`'s argument list to see that, as `get_posts()` is really [just a  wrapper around that class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1703).

> - **author** (*int*) - use author id.
> - **author_name** (*string*) - use
>     'user_nicename' (NOT name).
> - **author__in** (*array*) - use author id (available
>     with [Version 3.7](/Version_3.7)).
> - **author__not_in** (*array*) - use author
>     id (available with [Version
>     3.7](/Version_3.7)).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

What you want is `author` without the `post_` part. Try that, and it should work.

Comment: The simple things are the ones that drive it ... +1

Answer (score 0):

As it is totally unclear where `$post->post_author` comes from, the most likely issue is, that you are either not referring to the `$GLOBALS['post']` instance of `WP_Post` or that you have another query after your main loop, which replaces the main query.

You best shot probably will be to use [`wp_reset_query()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_query/). This will realign the `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` object which holds the current query with `$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']` again, which holds the *main* query and afterwards call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_postdata/) to rewind the main query.

If that doesn't help, then the chance that some plugin (or you) or the theme used `query_posts()`, which overwrites the global `$wp_the_query` object and therefore messes up your loop.